# Laplace transform rotational mechanical system

Tags: differential, transfer-function, electro-mechanical

I have a system with an input torque Te and output angular velocities w1 and w2. I have defined the outputs relative to the system however cannot seem to work out how to find GM(s). omega2 is the output from velocity w2 (all shown below):
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by GM(s)?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Gm(s) is the input torque over the output velocity form w2 so the transfer function. Tried converting everything to laplace but I don't understand how the question wants to format for omega2 when we have w1t and w2t

Comment: Uh -- you do realize that the convention is that "Laplace transform of \<lowercase\>(t) = \<uppercase\>(s)", so \$\mathcal L \left \lbrace \omega_1(t)\right \rbrace = \Omega_1(s)\$ -- yes?

Comment: Can you [edit] into the question, the equations you got after "*converting everything to Laplace*" ?

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 linear state variable equations. Laplace transform both sides of both of them. Eliminate the Laplace transform of w1. Calculate the ratio of the Laplace transforms of w2 and the input torque. You may need to assume that the system starts from rest to fade the initial angular velocity.

BTW. the state variable equations are useful as is if you know the constants as numerical values. You can in that case simulate the system even with a circuit analyzer or a spreadsheet.